# Using Tweepy to access Twitter Analytics?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Is there a way to access Twitter analytics (analytics.twitter.com) through Tweepy or any other Python library?

I need to get `media views` for a tweet, which is a metric that can be accessed when you export data from Twitter analytics.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API interface for analytics.twitter.com.

The only option that I am aware of is Twitter's Enterprise offering, which offers an [Engagement API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/metrics/get-tweet-engagement/overview.html) product. This requires an annual subscription. The documentation is a good starting point for what this API offers. I do not know whether there are Python libraries that offer specific access to the Engagement API, but even if they did, you would need to have a paid subscription and credentials from Twitter.